# Static pointer to class member causes undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, gcc4

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of my problem is:

```
class Callee
{
public:
  int m1()
  {
    return 5;
  }

  constexpr static int (Callee::*method)() = &Callee::m1;
};

template <class O> int call(O &o, int (O::*m)())
{
  return (o.*m)();
}

int main()
{
  Callee callee;
  return
    (callee.*Callee::method)() // works fine
    *
    call<Callee>(callee, Callee::method) // causes undefined reference in GCC
  ;
}
```

This code compiled in clang (3.4-1) but failed in gcc (4.8.4) with message:

```
undefined reference to `Callee::method'
```

Shorter, I can call some class method by its pointer directly, but I can't call it from templated function. (It is more unclear, than I inherit from *Callee*, because both methods works fine) **Why?**

Comment: Note that the code is well formed and link property in C++17, since `static constexpr` data member are inlined by default.

Comment: @Guillaume, Did you mean «properLy»?

Comment: yes. I guess I hit muscle memory